# Make simple text editor in android With Bold Italic and Underline

Tags: android-edittext, android

Make the EditText view  as text editor using Bold ,Italic and Underline styles similer to gmail compose

Comment: google it many solution available

Comment: what you have tried ? welcome to SO please search before posting a question.we will be more happy to help...:). and yes please read http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: i dint get any solution in google ..

Comment: @Android28: Name any besides my CWAC-RichEdit project. If there are others out there, I'd like to know about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not especially easy. I have a work-in-progress component in [my CWAC-RichEdit project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) for this.

In the end, you need to be able to apply `CharacterStyle` subclasses to the content of the `EditText`, typically when the user highlights some text. This involves getting the `Spannable` out of the `EditText` via `getText()`, getting selection information from the `EditText`, then applying the span. However:

- You have to take into account both adding and removing styles
- Some styles, like bullets or line alignment, are not strictly applied to the highlighted text, but rather to the line containing the highlighted text
- You need to have some UI to help with this (e.g., additional options in the action mode that pops up when the user highlights text)

I hope (:: crosses fingers ::) to be able to pick up work on my `RichEditText` again this fall to push its development along further.

Comment: Thank for your opensource code ..it works awesome. may be it try to do some modification on ur code and revent u back soon